# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-directml

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, windows-10, directx

I tried to install:

```
pip install tensorflow-directml
```

from [directml](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-directml/) on my Windows 10. I have an intel GUP and I was hoping I could use it. But I got the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-directml (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-directml
```

Did I miss something?

**EDIT:**
I'm using python 3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the library supports Python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7. Python3.8 is not supported at the moment  ([1](https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml#system-requirements)). Is your `pip` installation connected to any of those versions? Try using `pip --version` to confirm to which Python version it is connected. In case that it shows a Python 2 version, try using `pip3 install tensorflow-directml`.

Comment: Thank you .... I got: pip 22.0.3 from C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

Comment: When tried pip3 install tensorflow-directml. I got : ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'tensorflow-directml.'

Comment: Python 3.8 is not supported by `tensorflow-directml`. The linked docs say: "Note: Python 3.8 or newer is not currently supported. To use the official PyPi packages, the CPython interpreter is required. NumPy 1.19.4 is requires the KB4598291 to properly work on Windows." (Windows 10) and "Note: Python 3.8 or newer is not currently supported. To use the official PyPi packages, the CPython interpreter is required." (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Comment: As it stands, it seems that you'll need to use a different Python version (3.5, 3.6 or 3.7). I'm not sure of the progress on the project supporting Python 3.8, but maybe you could search in [their GitHub repository](https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml/) or create a new issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using 32-bit Python interpreter. You need a 64-bit Python interpreter for TensorFlow, as TensorFlow does not support 32-bit Python installations. Also check the version of Python you are using.